# Axis labels not showing up

Tags: r, plot, label, axis, correlation

I am having trouble with my axis, labels, etc. showing up in my plot. All I get are the data points.

My plot is showing up like this:

[image: plot]

My code is this

```
plot(Corr_SIMPIN_clean$PlanSum ~ Corr_SIMPIN_clean$POMP_Score_Flanker, xlab = "PlanSum", ylab = "POMP Score Flanker")
```

My data looks like this:

[image: data]

Comment: You probably have some weird `par` options set for you session. Close the current device with `dev.off()` and try again.

Answer (score 6):

As stated, I believe you have something weird at the graphical parameters. Do you have any `par()` lines after opening the graphical device? Try using `dev.off()` or `graphics.off()` and then start the graphic device again.

If not, try this:

- Add `xaxs="i",yaxs="i",xaxt="n",yaxt="n"` to your plot parameters.
- Add this two lines after the plot command:

  `axis(1, xaxp=c(minx,maxx,stepsx))`

  `axis(2, yaxp=c(miny,maxy,stepsy))`

Where `minx, maxx, miny, maxy` are the boundaries of the axis and `stepx, stepy` are the number of steps between markers in the axis.

Comment: You need `dev.off()`, not `device.off()`.